# Distrubuted TensorFlow : CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying the example provided here:
https://github.com/ischlag/distributed-tensorflow-example
I have two Machines: one working as Server and other as Worker. (Versions on both machine are 1.0.1)

I am getting the following error:

Variables initialized ...
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:193] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:ps/replica:0/task:0
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:193] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:1
I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/master.cc:193] CreateSession still waiting for response from worker: /job:worker/replica:0/task:2

Comment: Have you set your ips/ports in `parameter_servers = ["pc-01:2222"]
workers = [ "pc-02:2222", 
   "pc-03:2222",
   "pc-04:2222"]` ?

Comment: Yes. pc-01 -> is the ip address

Comment: give your ip port combinations. lf its on your local machine use localhost:2222 localhost:2223 etc

Comment: @Himaprasoon I have two different servers. <ip-addr1>:2222 and <ip-addr2>:2222 ... this is how i am giving

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue that I was able to fix by adding a third node as a master to the `ClusterSpec`. My `TF_CONFIG` environment variable looks something like:

```
    TF_CONFIG = { 
        'cluster' : { 
            'master' : [ master_node01:2222 ],
            'ps' : [ps_node01:2222, ...]
            'worker' : [worker_node01:2222, ...]}
        'environment' : 'cloud',
        'task': {'type': current_task, 'index': current_index}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after several hours of debugging, I found that the issue was because the order of the cluster_spec was incorrect.  The task_index was mismatched with the ps/worker list. After I changed the order, it was fixed.